# why my gobal variable does not increment each time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My global JavaScript variable increments up to `0` only why?

I'm using this code

**same page**

```
<?php $array = array('apple','banana','mango'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var my_delay = 1500; // 60000 millisecond = 1 minute
var globalIndex = -1;
var collectedArray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

function callItself() {
    $.ajax({
      url: ....
      success: function(data) {
          globalIndex = globalIndex + 1;
          console.log(globalIndex); // prints 0, 1, 2
          console.log(collectedArray[globalIndex]) // prints apple,undefined,undefined
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('finished this operation');
            callItself();
          }, my_delay);
        } // end of success
    });
  } // end of callItself

</script>
```

**my question:**

I'm getting `console.log(globalIndex); // prints 0 , 1, 2`

but for this `console.log(collectedArray[globalIndex]) // prints apple,undefined,undefined`

why am I getting `2 undefined`

Comment: You would have to show the rendered code in a  [mcve] since we cannot actually run your code

Comment: I believe you're getting undefined because your encoding your array as json. Objects don't have indexes only arrays.

Comment: i'm able to run it on `localhost` sucessfully which is `php 5` and my `server ` is `php 7` where i'm unable to run why?   without  changing any code to run it on `localhost`

Answer (score 1):

Do not update variables in success function directly unless you force the ajax call to be syncronous with `async: false`. A good Idea is to move the calculations to a call back function instead of forcing the ajax to be syncronous :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_delay = 150; // 60000 millisecond = 1 minute
var globalIndex = -1;
var collectedArray = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

function callItself() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'json.php',
      success: function(data) {
          mycallback()
        } // end of success
    });
  } // end of callItself


function mycallback(){

          globalIndex = globalIndex + 1;
          console.log(globalIndex);
          console.log(collectedArray[globalIndex]);
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('finished this operation');
            callItself();
          }, my_delay);
}
</script>
```